# scheduler for running python scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script which installs a build from server to a node.
Now I want to schedule the task to a specific time, so that it triggers automatically.

One way is the windows scheduler to trigger batch file which internally calls runs the python script.

Do python have built-in support for this.
It should be OS independent, runs on both windows and linux platform.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Advanced Python Scheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this lightweight scheduler before to handle cron tasks -> https://github.com/mrhwick/schedule

I'd highly recommend it.